# Python sorts months according to alphabet letters instead of months order

Tags: python, sum, pivot-table

I have a variable with dates named date.
First I convert to datetime:

```
df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df["date"]
```

Output:

```
      date          enrolled
0     2018-06-10    1
1     2018-06-10
2     2018-07-11    3
3     2018-07-11    1
4     2018-07-12
```

With this all my date data are mantained in ascending order, e.g, in months (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12). Although, as I want to see just date as month in my cumulative sum, I have to convert date column to month on my table where I calculate cumulative cases (sum) by month:

```
df['date'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x,'%b'))
df['date']
Ouput:
         date      enrolled
    0     Jun      1
    1     Jun      
    2     Jul      3
    3     Jul      1
    4     Jul
```

```
pvt=pd.pivot_table(df, index=['date'], value=e['enrolled'], aggfun{'enrolled':'count'})
```

Output:

```
enrolled    false true
    date
    Jul 4
    Jun 1
```

But I want to be:

```
enrolled    false true
    date
    Jun 1
    Jul 4
```

But this code changes the order of month, for instante, it puts Jul first and then Jun but before using this code, all date with month 6(Jun) were coming first and then 7(Jul).
Question: is there a change to do with the code to allowing my date respecting months order 6 (Jun) first, then 7 (Jul)??
Thanks.

Comment: Please post the actual output and the expected output

Comment: He need to convert month to Letters, such as Jan, Feb, Mar and so on, however, when he sorts the array, it will sort as order of alphabets, but he wants to keep order of month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set `date` as the index and then sort dataframe based on the index but before that use `CategoricalIndex` as:

```
df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index, 
                               categories=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May','Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug','Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], 
                               sorted=True)
```

Adding to it; I did not know there is a `Categorical` function in Pandas as well as the `CategoricalIndex`. You may use it as well, refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas.Categorical

Comment: I didnt understand. To where your code does fit on mine? Thanks

Comment: category.py:138: RuntimeWarning:

Values and categories have different dtypes. Did you mean to use
'Categorical.from_codes(codes, categories)'?
category.py:138: RuntimeWarning:

None of the categories were found in values. Did you mean to use
'Categorical.from_codes(codes, categories)'?

Comment: Try `df['date'] = pd.Categorical(df['date'], ordered=True, categories= ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May','Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug','Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])` before your `pivot_table` function.

Comment: It works. By the way, how to display month and year on this code: df['date'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x,'%b'))